# This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'x has been constrained to be type y'

Tags: types, f#

This code will generate the following warning

```
module TimeSeries

open System

type TimedValue<'T> = { ts : DateTime; value: 'T}
type TimeSerie<'T> = TimedValue<'T> seq

let t : TimedValue<'double> = { ts = DateTime.Today; value=5}
```

Warning:

> This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'double has been constrained to be type 'int'.

I am quite new to F#, I think the 5 is interpreted as an int and somehow F# tells me that I asked a double but it will be an int.

When I tried replacing `5` with `5.` this told me that it was still constrained by the float type.

Should I somehow cast it in double or just remove the declaration part `: TimedValue<'double>` and let F# deal with the types ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the apostrophe before `double`.

```
let t : TimedValue<double> = { ts = DateTime.Today; value=5.0}
```

A leading apostrophe is used to declare a type argument. So, you've declared a generic value but, by specifying `value=5` you've constrained the type arg to be `int`. You could also use a wildcard in place of the type arg:

```
let t : TimedValue<_> = { ts = DateTime.Today; value=5.0}
```

or remove the type annotation completely:

```
let t = { ts = DateTime.Today; value=5.0}
```

Comment: And note that the correct name for `double` in F# is actually `float`.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: Thanks Jon, I was wondering about this as well, I did not start reading your book yet, I am still on "Beginning F#"

Comment: [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340473.aspx) and [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353546.aspx) are both aliases for `System.Double`, but yes, `float` is more common/idiomatic.